# I need to convert this head recursion function to tail recursive

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

I need to convert this recursive function into tail recursive function but i am getting the wrong output can any help me out with this.

Here is the function definition:

> `f(n) = 3f(n − 1) - f(n − 2) + n`,
> with initial conditions `f(0) = 1` and `f(1) = 2`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int headRecursion(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        return 2;
    }

    return 3 * headRecursion(n - 1) - headRecursion(n - 2) + n;
}

int main(){
    cout << endl << headRecursion(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework. What have you tried? For the record, it would be much easier to turn this into iteration (a simple loop), than tail recursion.

Comment: i am stuck on this for quite a long time and it need to be done in tail only

Comment: tail recursion can always be rewritten as a loop, so is there a way to implement this algorithm using a loop? (it's not always possible)

Comment: Think about how you would calculate this by hand. Would you do it recursively separately on f(n-1) and f(n-2)? Or would you combine the recursive calls somehow?

Comment: BTW, I've often seen the expression "non-tail-recursive", but never "head-recursive".

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an interesting problem. We can start with how to implement as a loop:

```
int minus2 = 1;
int minus1 = 2;

if (n == 0) return minus2;
if (n == 1) return minus1;
for( int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    int next = minus1 * 3 - minus2 + i;
    minus2 = minus1;
    minus1 = next;
}
return minus1;
```

The takeaway is we need to count UP. In order to make this tail recursive we need to pass in our accumulators (there is no reason to do this other than to show off, but it adds nothing to readability or efficiency)

```
int tailRecursive(int minus2, int minus1, int step, int n)
{
    if (step == n) return minus1;
    return tailRecursive(minus1, minus1*3 - minus2 + step+1, step+1, n);
}
```

you can use an intermediate to set it up and handle the n==0 case.

```
int calcIt(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    // step must start with 1, since we handled 0 above
    return tailRecursive(1, 2, 1, n);
}
```

Comment: I know this isn't quite accurate, but minor tweaks should make it correct.

Comment: see it in action https://www.mycompiler.io/view/EYTvQCv

Comment: I think it's quite a convoluted thought process to go from recursive to loop to recursive again. Recursion is much more high-level and much more natural and easy to understand for humans than loops. Going from recursion to iteration then back to recursion is a bit counterproductive.

Comment: @Stef well that's the opposite of what computer science students always think. Recursion is very unintuitive. It also leads to poor code performance and stack overflows. The point is, in order to make something tail recursive, it has to be possible within a loop, so seeing the loop helps imagine the tail recursive solution.

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines:

```
std::pair<int, int> next_result(std::pair<int, int> prev_result, int n) {
  return {3*prev_result.first - prev_result.second + n, prev_result.first};
}

std::pair<int, int> tailRecursion(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return {1, 0};
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return {2, 1};
    }
    return next_result(tailRecursion(n-1), n);
}

int compute(int n) {
    return tailRecursion(n).first;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << compute(3) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/faW9Pdfff)

The key is that you need a function that computes a pair `{f(n), f(n-1)}` given the previously computed pair `{f(n-1), f(n-2)}`

Comment: Doesn't the fact that your function `tailRecursion` feeds the result of `tailRecursion(n-1)` to `next_result` make this not tail-recursive?

Comment: this is not tail recursive. Tail recursion does not need any of the local variables after it returns